# How do I call a specific Controller Action to test code within it, especially session variables?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using MVC5 on ASP.NET 4.5

I want to debug specific Controller Actions without running the whole application where I would need to know how to navigate to the specific Action, in addition to it taking much time, since I have much code to refactor and test.

I have considered Unit Tests, but using the debugger seems more appropriate for what I am doing.

Also I have session variables within the Action Code.

The closest I have come to a solution is to have a wrapper Action in Home ie:

```
    public ActionResult Tx()
    {
        return new MyApp.Areas.Area1.Controllers.OrderController().Index();
    }
```

I would then copy and paste the relevant Namespace, Controller and Action with any relevant parms into the "Tx" Action.

This does invoke the relevant Action without me needing to navigate to the specific Action. I just call Home/Tx. However I am getting null exception errors with my Session variable code:

```
Session["OrderID"]=null
```

Debugging the Action, with the Session variables works fine when I navigate directly from the application. When I use Home/Tx it is still on the Dev Web Server and within the Debug process, but perhaps I am in a new context as another Action is creating the Controller.

1) Any idea why my idea does not work with Session variables?

2) If anybody has a better idea on how to invoke specific Controller Actions then I would appreciate that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the Initialize method on your controller before using it.  Try something like:

```
    var httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
    var routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(httpContext);

    var controller = new MyApp.Areas.Area1.Controllers.OrderController(); 
    controller.Initialize(new RequestContext(httpContext, routeData)); 
    return controller.Index();
```

Comment: Thanks for this.. What namespaces do I need via "using". I suspect "using System.Web;", "using System.Web.Routing;", but there is another as "HttpContext.Current" is unknown.

Comment: HttpContext is in System.Web. I'm not sure where you're calling this from though. You very well may have a the current context available to you.